# Will the attack strength of my evee carry over to its evolved form?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have several higher evees, one of which I am going to evolve. One evee, at cp 267, has a 70 dig attack, and the other cp 325 evee has a much weaker 40 attack. Will evolving the lower evee produce an über powerful attack? I am hoping so, as this will be my first vaporeon, and it will complete my evee team.

Answer (score 3):

When you evolve a Pokemon, their IVs (Attack, Damage, and Stamina) will all stay the exact same as the pre-evolved form, as will their level. As a result, an evolved Pokemon will *also* experience a CP gain to keep them at the same level. Therefore, it makes more sense to evolve the higher-IV Eevee.

However, there is no guarantee as to what moves you get when you evolve a Pokemon, as they are randomly selected from an "allowable list" from each species. Therefore, your high-IV Eevee may become a high-IV Flareon with a horrible moveset. At the same time, your low-IV Eevee may become a low-IV Jolteon with the best possible moveset.

Typically, it is recommended to evolve the higher IV Pokemon, though.

Answer (score 0):

The higher the cp the higher the evolved evolution will be the water type u can get by nicknaming it rainer  it has the most cp and HP if u nickname one sparky he's the fastest and pyro the fire type but all depends on what you're facing

Comment: I know that, but should I evolve the eevee with a higher attack strength, or the eevee higher in cp. like does the attack of the base pokemon influence the attack strength of the evolved pokemon?

Answer (score 0):

As far by the community is concerned, the moves learned are completely random on Evolution.